# Bootstrap Validator with angular

Tags: angularjs

I have problems with the bootstrap-validator plugin in angular:

this is my directive:

```
module.registerDirective('bootstrapUserForm', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function(scope, form){
            form.bootstrapValidator({
                feedbackIcons : {
                    valid : 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid : 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating : 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                fields : {
                    title: {
                        validators : {
                            notEmpty : {
                                message : 'Bitte geben Sie einen Titel ein'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    firstname: {
                        validators : {
                            notEmpty : {
                                message : 'Bitte geben Sie einen Vornamen ein'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and this is my form:

```
<bootstrapUserForm id="smart-form-register" class="smart-form" action="/api/test" bootstrapUserForm>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="row">

                <section>
                    <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="mustermannm" ng-model="userdata.username">
                        <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Bitte geben Sie einen Benutzernamen ein</b> </label>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="m.mustermann@gmail.com" ng-model="userdata.email">
                        <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Bitte geben Sie eine Emailadresse ein</b> </label>
                </section>
    </fieldset>       
    <footer>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" data-ui-sref="app.maindata.users">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
            Zurück
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
            Erstellen
        </button>
    </footer>
</bootstrapUserForm>
```

The form is only a snipped.

Bootstrap validator dont validate the data. I also added the directive name as html attribute, but I think there where an error in my directive. I´am new to angular and directives.

Answer (score 0):

add novalidate in form tag and use bootstrap-user-form then try..

```
   <bootstrap-user-form novalidate id="smart-form-register" class="smart-form" action="/api/test" bootstrapUserForm>
<fieldset>
    <div class="row">

            <section>
                <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="mustermannm" ng-model="userdata.username">
                    <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Bitte geben Sie einen Benutzernamen ein</b> </label>
            </section>
            <section>
                <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="m.mustermann@gmail.com" ng-model="userdata.email">
                    <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Bitte geben Sie eine Emailadresse ein</b> </label>
            </section>
</fieldset>       
<footer>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" data-ui-sref="app.maindata.users">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
        Zurück
    </button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">
        <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
        Erstellen
    </button>
</footer>
```

Comment: I'm afraid not. No messages and the post request were also not fireing.